# How to create racks in a hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to do data placement in a hadoop cluster and  I came across that it can be done using racks. I wanted to know how to create those racks. Is there any particular way to do it or will it be done automatically? Can anyone please help me as to how to create racks in a cluster.What steps need to be followed. Thank you.

Comment: http://free-hadoop-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/04/rack-awareness.html

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Rack_Awareness

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-692

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a rack-topology script. 2)Copy it to the /etc/Hadoop/conf directory on all cluster nodes.
Run rack-topology.sh on each cluster. 3)modify core-site.xml as          
     net.topology.script.file.name
     /etc/hadoop/conf/rack-topology.sh